# How to decrypt RSA text from p, q and d ('data greater than mod len' error)

Tags: perl, rsa

I'm trying to decrypt some text using the p, q & d RSA parameters. This is my code:

```
use Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA;

my $cipher_text = '21822641296030233094227313655848509440605583067924377543599838215888039562622129112129822895080408267928468534668157995224253484645729278749085139763130764635317451011719149549123004731102607506049461610797920861018820451965633121194245016524243388070479379308761222809258576639629711274935572812821629596774863705897518352434753834386314245125246066390859225185066330366811073476496684635339997048026729834327425483254569562337608819782060439696539771993138092386150797070320410153423661265108318321693803297014167486821806691214248145774922909225478697375135263295662839076540338821496045675607198591575588621659609';
my ($p, $q, $d) = ( 
  Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_decimal('165531801682935357262784768224825567629908164720968584885888440012850606062817307481747891600670103793664550471500745014914678541225436018211939431390053926336912952441897829541865006123774689488999658248640982182224222754377835611000656130261325362538051966725284846900143448968656908810497538272078057741753'),
  Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_decimal('161793529444258956657578160951133315733795687396943555542529109270426552912409876020630999202216058708771830991232800413521618941159308875874915491167328976063871230426911602170436153334762815254160844789590951618176633523800724364347786188020741173210831867848084340389279221308498668063580976312456313708227'),
  Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_decimal('4726230781685159301129128926091597612191418774972180765730674153946543720175721375641429858288249804644693058129864174539693448753576337835228363947222471089804797108134073771268482070990981157234925023770851307423738245681533737104667110764794379344770670194385194083716134044195705274587539907463141446593440244816853972305589231700346121402158165643863387848676660192091263041614047764528653983145902131144938355047165291147495652786645127063867131916536922764685613090037417336307735248968661966233168304037079723873034096551522712515691482108402916631034263410195810822874808411813091006049133015592459279891521'),
);

my $n    = $p->mul($q, Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum::CTX->new());

# I use d as e because e is mandatory and I don't have it. Later I'll use public_decrypt instead of decrypt.
my $rsa  = Crypt::OpenSSL::RSA->new_key_from_parameters($n, $d, undef, $p, $q);
my $text = $rsa->public_decrypt($cipher_text);
```

But that gives me:

```
RSA.xs:202: OpenSSL error: data greater than mod len at test.pl line 14
```

Which I don't really know what means, data is not greater that d or n.

:-?

**EDITED**

The following python code works so I far as I know the keys and data are good.

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

p = 165531801682935357262784768224825567629908164720968584885888440012850606062817307481747891600670103793664550471500745014914678541225436018211939431390053926336912952441897829541865006123774689488999658248640982182224222754377835611000656130261325362538051966725284846900143448968656908810497538272078057741753
q = 161793529444258956657578160951133315733795687396943555542529109270426552912409876020630999202216058708771830991232800413521618941159308875874915491167328976063871230426911602170436153334762815254160844789590951618176633523800724364347786188020741173210831867848084340389279221308498668063580976312456313708227
d = 4726230781685159301129128926091597612191418774972180765730674153946543720175721375641429858288249804644693058129864174539693448753576337835228363947222471089804797108134073771268482070990981157234925023770851307423738245681533737104667110764794379344770670194385194083716134044195705274587539907463141446593440244816853972305589231700346121402158165643863387848676660192091263041614047764528653983145902131144938355047165291147495652786645127063867131916536922764685613090037417336307735248968661966233168304037079723873034096551522712515691482108402916631034263410195810822874808411813091006049133015592459279891521
n = p * q
cypher_text = 21822641296030233094227313655848509440605583067924377543599838215888039562622129112129822895080408267928468534668157995224253484645729278749085139763130764635317451011719149549123004731102607506049461610797920861018820451965633121194245016524243388070479379308761222809258576639629711274935572812821629596774863705897518352434753834386314245125246066390859225185066330366811073476496684635339997048026729834327425483254569562337608819782060439696539771993138092386150797070320410153423661265108318321693803297014167486821806691214248145774922909225478697375135263295662839076540338821496045675607198591575588621659609

decrypter = RSA.construct((n, 0L, d, p, q))
text = decrypter.key._decrypt(cypher_text)
print(text)
```

Comment: You need to have a correct value for d if you want to decrypt. Your comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: I've just edited and added a python code that is working, so text, p, q and d must be ok.
I don't know what part of the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: `# I use d as e because e is mandatory and I don't have it. Later I'll use public_decrypt instead of decrypt.` doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, probably I'm wrong at some point since the code doesn't work :(. Still that make sense to me: 1. The `new_key_from_parameters` needs the public key to create a key. 2. The `public_decrypt` decrypts using the public key. 3. Because I don't have the public key I cannot create the key in a straight way but I can workaround it passing the private key as public and then using `public_decrypt` which is suppose to decrypt using the public key (that in my case is the private)

Comment: Maybe I'm confused. The plaintext looks pretty random to me. What is it exactly?

Comment: It is a session id so I think is normal that looks like random. Basically (I'm trying to connect to Mega service from Perl, following these Python examples: http://julien-marchand.fr/blog/using-mega-api-with-python-examples/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error signifies that there's a mismatch between the key size and the data.
I'm not a python expert but IIRC it handles big numbers in core, and you've got cipher_text as a text string.

The cipher text looks like a decimal which we want as a binary string, so I think you want:

```
my $cipher_text = Crypt::OpenSSL::Bignum->new_from_decimal( '21822....' )->to_bin;
```

This turns out to be 256 bytes which sounds about right.

Now the error is:
    RSA.xs:202: OpenSSL error: unknown padding type at rsa.pl line 20

I'm not sure about this, but I have to take the kids out now anyway :)

Comment: Thanks! You are absolutely right. For the padding I just added `$rsa->use_no_padding();`